# Access to object property within System.Action

Tags: c#, delegates

There are two classes:

```
public abstract class BaseObject
{
    public string Status {get; set;}

    public List<string> StatusHistory {get; set;}

    protected abstract void ExecuteInternal();

    public void Execute()
    {
        this.Status = "Started";

        this.ExecuteInternal();

        this.Status = "Finished";
    }

    // on status changed event: adding current status to StatusHistory list
}

public class SomeObject : BaseObject
{
    public System.Action Action {get; set;}

    public SomeObject() : this(null)
    {
    }

    public SomeObject(System.Action action)
    {
        this.Action = action;
    }

    protected override void ExecuteInternal()
    {
        this.Action();
    }
}
```

Using this object, I want to set Status property in time Action would be executed:

```
 const string customStatus = "Custom status";

 var someObject= new SomeObject(() => Status = customStatus);

 someObject.Execute();
```

to verify that the customStatus was setted indeed:

```
 if (!HistoryStatus.Contains(customStatus))
 {
     // throw an exception
 }
```

Here an error occurs: The name 'Status' does not exist in the current context.

How could I set the property within the Action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, this is overcomplicating things, *instead I'd highly suggest using the object initialiser syntax*:

```
var someObject = new SomeObject() { Status = customStatus};
```

Nevertheless, you can solve your current issue, by using `System.Action<SomeObject>` which specifies the type of input expected instead of `System.Action` then modify the respective places in your code:

```
class SomeObject
{
        public System.Action<SomeObject> Action {get; set;}

        public string Status {get; set;}

        public SomeObject() : this(null)
        {
        }

        public SomeObject(System.Action<SomeObject> action)
        {
            this.Action = action;
        }

        public void Execute()
        {
            this.Action(this);
        }
}
```

Then invoke as follows:

```
const string customStatus = "Custom status";
var someObject= new SomeObject((s) => s.Status = customStatus);
```

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but I guess the poster needs an action because there's logic in "customStatus" section of `var someObject = new SomeObject() { Status = customStatus};` which is again quite an anti pattern.

Comment: Sorry, I have simplified too much my case. Now I have added some more code

Answer (score 0):

I need something like this:

```
        const string customStatus = "Custom status";

        var someObject = new SomeObject();

        someObject.Action = () => someObject.Status = customStatus;
```